# De-hulling pumpkin seeds for research

Tags: pumpkin

I want to conduct research on the inner part of the pumpkin seeds. I find it difficult to remove the shells one by one by hand. What is the best method for dehulling pumpkin seeds (for research purposes)?

Comment: Welcome! Does it matter if the pumpkin seed retains it shape, or will slightly bashed up do?

Comment: Comment on EDIT: I understand that the initial subject heading was a tad convoluted, however the OP did state RESEARCH not STUDY, this could change the meaning of the question as initially put.

Comment: I agree that study can be different than research and what is Halo?

Comment: @Paparazzi I assume typo of "hello"